# Erro ao escrever em tabela SQL a partir de WindowsForm

Tags: sql, conversão

Estou a tentar escrever numa tabela vários campos de uma Windows Form App.
Alguns desses campos são foreign keys de outras tabelas.
Se os campos tiverem valores, a instrução SQL executa-se mas se não tiverem valores obtenho um erro de conversão (Text to Int).

```
    SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("insert into tb_imagem (imagem,nome_imagem,descr_imagem,ND,iddiag,idlesao,idlesao1,idlesao2,idlesao3,idlesao4) values (@imagem,@nome_imagem,@descr_imagem,@ND,@iddiag,@idlesao,@idlesao1,@idlesao2,@idlesao3,@idlesao4)", con);
    SqlCommand cmdInteiro = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

    SqlParameter imagem = new SqlParameter("@imagem", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
    SqlParameter nome_imagem = new SqlParameter("@nome_imagem", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter descr_imagem = new SqlParameter("@descr_imagem", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    SqlParameter ND = new SqlParameter("@ND", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter iddiag = new SqlParameter("@iddiag", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter idlesao = new SqlParameter("@idlesao", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter idlesao1 = new SqlParameter("@idlesao1", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter idlesao2 = new SqlParameter("@idlesao2", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter idlesao3 = new SqlParameter("@idlesao3", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter idlesao4 = new SqlParameter("@idlesao4", SqlDbType.Int);

    imagem.Value = foto;
    nome_imagem.Value = TextBoxNomeImagem.Text;
    descr_imagem.Value = TextBoxDescrImagem.Text;
    iddiag.Value = TextBoxiddiag.Text;
    idlesao.Value = TextBoxidlesao.Text;
    idlesao1.Value = TextBoxidlesao1.Text;
    idlesao2.Value = TextBoxidlesao2.Text;
    idlesao3.Value = TextBoxidlesao3.Text;
    idlesao4.Value = TextBoxidlesao4.Text;
    ND.Value = TextBoxND.Text);
```

Alguma ideia do que pode estar a passar-se e como resolver?

Obrigado
Adriano

Comment: Isso deve estar acontecendo porque o campo está vazio (nulo) e ao tentar converter não consegue. Adriano, você verificou essa possibilidade?

Answer (score 0):

A exceção é do tipo `ArgumentNullException`, pois o `SqlParameter` faz uma conversão interna usando o `System.Int32.Parse(string)` para coletar o dado da propriedade `parametro.Value`. Caso valor seja nulo(que seria um textbox.text vazio) a exceção é lançada Para obter um retorno zero use:

```
parametro.Value = Convert.ToInt32(seusTextBoxidlesao.Text);
```

Ou então vc pode usar o método `AddWithParameter();` segue exemplo abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com esse método creio que você não vai obter qualquer problema.

Comment: Muito obrigado Paulo Ricardo. Funcionou bem a sua segunda opção.

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno @Adriano. se foi útil pra vc, sinaliza a resposta para dar uma moral né?

Comment: Paulo Ricardo, sinalizei mas como tenho reputação < 15 (newbie) não aparece.